# How to show duplicate axis label on the X-Axis of a BarChart in Flutter Charts?

Tags: flutter, charts, bar-chart

Is there any way to show duplicate axis label in BarChart of Flutter_chart library in the domainAxis property. I am using charts_flutter library (https://pub.dev/packages/charts_flutter#-installing-tab-).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but for anyone else looking for this, an easy workaround is to symmetrically add spaces to repeated labels. This can be done using a [callable class](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#callable-classes) for your domain function, so that you can keep track of repeats:

```
class Labeler {
  final existingLabels = <String>[];

  String call(Data data, int index) {
    String baseLabel = data.toString();
    int existingCount = existingLabels.where((element) => element == baseLabel).length;
    existingLabels.add(baseLabel);
    return ' ' * existingCount + baseLabel + ' ' * existingCount;
  }
}
```

You can then create an instance and set it as your `domainFn`.